# Work with bytes in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have to get bytes array and send it into socket.

The structure looks like: 1 byte + 2 bytes + 2 bytes.

First byte is number '5', second 2 bytes should be taken from variable `first`, third 2 bytes should be taken from variable `second`. What's the right way to do this in python?

```
id = 5      # Fill as 1 byte
first = 42  # Fill as 2 bytes
second = 58 # The same as first
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>> id, first, second = 5, 42, 58
>>> struct.pack('>bhb', id, first, second)
b'\x05\x00*:'
```

You may want to figure out if your data is a) little or big endian and b) is signed or unsigned; the example above use big-endian ordering and signed values.

The result (in python 3) is a `bytes` object.

Comment: @Ockonal: then use the '>' format marker at the start; my example now uses that.

Comment: Consider creating a Struct object (from the same module) if the byte-packing occurs repeatedly.

Comment: According to the question the variable named 'second' should be two bytes too.